# MEAN Project - Organization

Tags: node.js, git, angularjs, express, mean-stack

I am wondering what are your best practices for a Single Web Page app project using the MEAN stack (MongoDB, Express, Angular and Node.js).

Right now we have the following organization:

- One Git repository for the Angular Client side code
- One Git repo for the node.js & express server side code.

I saw browsing some blogs and checking [node.js boilerplate](http://www.nodeboilerplate.com) that a common strucure is to have only one repository to handle Angular Code and Server code.

I'd like to know, from the community, if this approach is really better than having 2 difference repo in terms of versioning, easy to deploy etc...

From my personal point of view, I don't see that much difference...

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see much difference as well. It should actually be driven by the team. Your code organization could be beneficial if you had a separate front-end and back-end teams. I've seen an environment when UI guys only downloaded UI portion and hooked up to REST back-end deployed somewhere on DEV server.

Number 2 is release procedure. If your front-end and back-end are tightly coupled they will be  released together for 99%. Then you don't need to handle 2 repos. However if your back-end will serve as REST service end-point for other clients, not only your UI and you plan to release front-end changes without touching the back-end (no downtime for external clients) you may want to use two separate repos.

Also think about your CI server. You may want to run front-end an back-end builds and tests separately. However for most CI servers it does not matter either it is one repo or two.

Comment: Thanks to confirm what i thought ^^So for this project, we'll go with two repo, as the server and front-end are not really coupled !